# Have an input display a text but with a different value

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have the following form:

```
<form>

  <input type="button" value="1" >
  <input type="button" value="2">
  <input type="button" value="3">
  <input type="button" value="4">

  <button>Create account</button>

</form>
```

Those values are to choose a package from a database (those are the IDs). But on the screen I don't want them to display a number but a name (basic, advanced, pro, pro+). Is it possible to have a value and display a different text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use input type `radio` for choose a different type of value.

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
<label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="1"> Basic </label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="1"> Advanced </label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="3"> Pro</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="4"> Pro + </label>
<button type="submit">Create account</button>
</form>
```

Comment: But I want to display a button, not radio

Comment: Could you please share your expected output design? any design or ui ?

Comment: I ended up using radio, I tried my best to make it look like a button, thx

Answer (score 2):

Use a `button` element:

```html
<form>
  <button type="button" value="1">Basic</button>
  <button type="button" value="2">Advanced</button>
  <button type="button" value="3">Pro</button>
  <button type="button" value="4">Pro+</button>

  <button>Create account</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

style a placeholder or data-attribute, or a for= label.